# Javascript error: 'undefined is not a function' when trying to remove and add class to li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container with **li** elements nested inside a **ul** element.  I'm trying to use Javascript to remove and add a class called **active** when an li element in the container is selected.  However when I click on the class, the **li element class** is neither added or removed.  When I check the web developer in my browser, I get the message **'undefined is not a function'**

HTML:

```
<div class="about_nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="#story">Our Story</a></li>
        <li><a href="#blocks">International Blocks</a></li>
        <li><a href="#works">How it works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#gift">The Perfect Gift</a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.about_nav {
   background: no-repeat #FFF 12px 3px;
   box-shadow:0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.41);
   width:25%;
   margin:35px 20px 20px 70px;
   float:left;
   position:fixed;
}

.about_nav ul {
   margin-top:0;
   margin-bottom:0;
   padding-left:0;
   list-style:none;
   background-color:#FFF;
}

.about_nav li {
   margin-top:2px;
   margin-left:0px;
   position:relative;
   display:block;
}

.about_nav li:hover {
   background:#eee;
   border-radius:4px;  
}

.about_nav li>a {
   color:#428bca;
   text-decoration:none;
   padding:10px 15px;
   position:relative;
   display:block;
 }

.about_nav li>a:hover {
   color:#2a6496;
   text-decoration:none;
   border-radius:4px;
 }

.about_nav li.active>a,
.about_nav li.active>a:hover,
.about_nav li.active>a:focus {
   color:#FFF;
   background-color:#428bca;
 }
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $( document ).ready(function() {
   $('.about_nav li').on('click', function(e) {
    $('.about_nav li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
      });
   });
</script>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are loading jQuery right?...At what point are your receiving that error. On `click` or on the firing of the `ready` function?

Comment: Works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q1dkh34h/ -- provided you load jQuery...

Comment: so... where did the error occur?

Comment: You don't have jQuery included I guess.

Comment: I'm using jQuery from the GoogleApi's library.  See my edit above.

Comment: You're using `.on()` which wasn't included in jQuery until 1.7. You're using 1.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a severely outdated version of jQuery. The problem is that [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) was not added until version *1.7*. You're using *1.4*. Upgrade you're jQuery version and it should work fine.

Comment: Just upgraded my jQuery version and now it works fine.  Thank you @War10ck

Answer (score -3):

```
<div class="about_nav">
    <ul>
        <li class="item"><a href="#story">Our Story</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#blocks">International Blocks</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#works">How it works</a></li>
        <li class="item"><a href="#gift">The Perfect Gift</a></li>
    </ul>    
</div>

 $('.item').on('click', function(this){
    $('.item').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
      });
```

actually, I added the same class for every item you click, it is called a global class, then when somebody press this item you just remove the class active from all items that has "item" class.

$('.about_nav').onclick didn't work because you was catching the clicks not from ul 'parrent' but form the ul li 'childs'

Comment: also, don't forget to include a jquery library

Comment: We don't usually just dump code without an explanation as an answer.

Comment: explained that as well